# Drawing points with with median lines in seaborn using stripplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following plot in seaborn:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({"sample": ["X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Y"],
                       "value": [0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8],
                       "rep": ["a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"]})
plt.figure()
ax = sns.stripplot(x="sample", y="value", edgecolor="none",
                   hue="sample", palette="Set1", data=df)

# how to plot median line?
plt.show()
```

It plots the points in gray scale colors instead of using `Set1` and only shows `X` in the legend and not `Y`:

[image: s]

I also want to add a horizontal line at the median for `X` and `Y`. how can this be done? `factorplot` doesn't appear to have a horizontal line option.

Comment: What version of seaborn? The grayscale points should not be occurring in 0.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may plot lines by using matplolib. Pandas may calculate medians value for your dataset. I use seaborn 0.7.0 in this example:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = DataFrame({"sample": ["X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Y"],
                       "value": [0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8],
                       "rep": ["a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"]})
# calc medians
xmed = df.loc[df["sample"] == 'X'].median()['value']
ymed = df.loc[df["sample"] == 'Y'].median()['value']

sns.stripplot(x="sample", y="value", edgecolor="none",
 hue="sample", palette="Set1", data=df)

x = plt.gca().axes.get_xlim()

# how to plot median line?
plt.plot(x, len(x) * [xmed], sns.xkcd_rgb["pale red"])
plt.plot(x, len(x) * [ymed], sns.xkcd_rgb["denim blue"])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

We can limit the width of each median line to its respective column by looping through the Axes ticks and ticklabels after generating the stripplot. This also enables the code to operate independent of the number of samples (columns) to be plotted.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import seaborn as sns
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    df = pd.DataFrame({"sample": ["X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Y"],
                       "value": [0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8],
                       "rep": ["a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"]})

    ax = sns.stripplot(x="sample", y="value", data=df, palette="Set1", s=8)

    # distance across the "X" or "Y" stipplot column to span, in this case 40%
    median_width = 0.4

    for tick, text in zip(ax.get_xticks(), ax.get_xticklabels()):
        sample_name = text.get_text()  # "X" or "Y"

        # calculate the median value for all replicates of either X or Y
        median_val = df[df['sample']==sample_name].value.median()

        # plot horizontal lines across the column, centered on the tick
        ax.plot([tick-median_width/2, tick+median_width/2], [median_val, median_val],
                lw=4, color='k')

    plt.show()
```

seaborn stripplot with median lines drawn:
[image: seaborn stripplot with median lines drawn]

Comment: Following your example, I get the error, "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_xticks'". Any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: @SummerEla - do you get that error when running the example code or a modification of it? I just retried the example with versions 3.3.1 and 0.10.1 of matplotlib and seaborn, respectively, and it works on my end. Without knowing more it is hard to say, but the error implies for some reason `ax` is a list rather than a matplotlib Axes. Are you creating multiple plots?