# Overplot the mean line in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'd like to get two lines (red and green) with the average of my data points in green and average of my data points in red. I'm using the following code, but it's not working. It's only showing the red and green data points, without the red average line

```
 sns.set(rc={"figure.figsize": (16, 8)})
ax = events_all_metrics[["event_name","kambi_payback"]].plot(x="event_name", style='.',use_index=False, color ='green')
events_all_metrics[["event_name","pinny_payback"]].plot(x="event_name",style='.', color='red', ax=ax)
plt.tick_params(
    axis='x',          # changes apply to the x-axis
    which='both',      # both major and minor ticks are affected
    bottom='off',      # ticks along the bottom edge are off
    top='off',         # ticks along the top edge are off
    labelbottom='off')
plt.legend(loc=4, prop={'size': 15})

pinny_mean = events_all_metrics["pinny_payback"].mean()
ax.plot(pinny_mean, label='Pinny Mean', linestyle='--', color='red')
plt.show()
```

[image: kambi_pinny]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drawing points with with median lines in seaborn using stripplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37619952/drawing-points-with-with-median-lines-in-seaborn-using-stripplot)

Answer (score 2):

This is not working because your `pinny_mean` is a single value in y. `plot` needs points in y and x. In this case I recommend you use [`plt.axhline`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axhline.html) instead of `plot`. It plots a line of constant y that covers the whole range in x. For your example:

```
plt.axhline(y=pinny_mean, label='Pinny Mean', linestyle='--', color='red')
```

Comment: Thanks Tiago. Also I'd like to change the label names in the image. I've set label = "new name" inside bot plot parts but it isn't working. Any suggestion?

Comment: You need to call `plt.legend` only after you've plotted all the labelled objects.